# How to search in table using multiple key and value?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

I am trying to implement multiple select search using angular and spring boot.
I got the select data form frontend in key and value pair. How can i write query to get the data from table?

I am getting the data like this `{"groom_Bride":"groom","ageFrom":"18","ageTo":"24","city":"Graduate","education":"Graduate"}`

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/Search")
    String showSingleProduct(@RequestParam(value = "data", required = false) String data) {

    System.out.println("this is data" +data);

    return "";
```

Please tell me how can i write query for search?

Comment: try @RequestParam Map allRequestParams, and then use this map to write query according to your business rules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the skeleton using MVC.
Return results as single object/List of your ProductClass so it is easy to use.

```
//in controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/Search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
ProductClass showSingleProduct(@RequestParam Map allRequestParams) {
    
    return someService.getSingleProduct(allRequestParams);
}

// in service class
ProductClass getSingleProduct(Map allRequestParams){
   String query = getQuery(allRequestParams); // write query as needed using the map 
   return productRepository.getProduct(query);
}

// in repository
 ProductClass getProduct(String query){ 
    return entityManager.createNativeQuery(query,ProductClass.class).getSingleResult();
 }
```

I gave this skeleton so that its easier for you if you are a beginner in SpringBoot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple JSON parser library for Java. For example Jackson https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/#5-minute-tutorial-streaming-parser-generator

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/Search")
String showSingleProduct(@RequestParam(value = "data", required = false) String data) {

    // Parse String to Map
    Map<String,Object> mapData = new ObjectMapper().readValue(data, HashMap.class);
   
    // Write query
    // String bride = mapData.get("groom_Bride")
    // ....
}
```